# Return Multiple Blank (If) Conditions (IsBlank)

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a problem with this forumula:

`=LOWER(IF(D1="";IF(C1="";IF(B1="";IF(A1="";"";A1);A1&"."&B1);A1&"."&B1&"."&C1);A1&"."&B1&"."&C1&"."&D1))`

on pre 2011 Excel work's fine but on Excel 2011 it dosen't work .. why?

I want to use it to make the usernames

```
  A     B      C     D           E
NAME1 NAME2  NAME3 NAME4    =name1.name2.name3.name4  (if name3 missing, then no extra dot(leave blank))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't SHOUT when asking your question. It makes it harder to read, and wastes the time of those of us who have to go in and fix it. The easier it is for people to read, the quicker you're likely to get an answer. Also, it's not necessary to provide the same information in the title that's in the tags; that's what tags are for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you will always get an extra dot when name3 is missing, using that formula in any version of excel. Try this version

`=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A1="";"";"."&A1)&IF(B1="";"";"."&B1)&IF(C1="";"";"."&C1)&IF(D1="";"";"."&D1);".";"";1))`

All populated cells are preceded by "." in the concatenation.....SUBSTITUTE removes the first "." that isn't required.